# cannot automate some objects which uses degrafa libraries

Tags: apache-flex, degrafa

In our application ,we have diagrams which make useof degrafa libraries.When this application is automated with flexmonkey any operation done on these diagrams are not recorded nor played back.

Rest of the application like filling the textfield and dropdown are working fine.

Is there any way I could automate these degrafa diagrams like clicking on it or changing the description.

Thanks

Comment: Not unless you extend degrafa to support automation.

Comment: Thanks JAX,Can you please elaborate it. Also please direct me to the documents sites if available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Degrafa libs uses the [Automation framework](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ec5.html) in Flex.  If you want it to work, you'll need to implement some key interfaces and helper classes for it to work.

Comment: JAX,Is there any document which I can follow to do this?

Comment: That link I just posted is a good start, other than that, try to google around for examples or just look at the Flex code for their components.